# How to get the data for the current week from MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I wanted to know how I can get the records for the current week.

The query I am using is  :

```
DECLARE @TableX TABLE

([Date] DATETIME)

INSERT INTO @TableX

SELECT '2014-2-17' UNION ALL

SELECT '2014-2-18' UNION ALL

SELECT '2014-2-19' UNION ALL

SELECT '2014-2-20' UNION ALL

SELECT '2014-2-21'


SELECT * FROM @TableX

WHERE Date >= DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()) / 7 * 7, 0)
AND  Date <= DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, -1, GETDATE()), 0)
```

The query I have wrote doesn't produce the data correctly ? Can anyone please tell me what is wrong in the query.

The records I get from this query is :

```
2014-02-17 00:00:00.000
2014-02-18 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: I am not getting the records for the current week

Comment: I am just getting two days record

Comment: MS SQL 2008 that I am using.

Comment: As an aside: `INSERT INTO @TableX VALUES ( '2014-2-17' ), ( '2014-2-18' ), ( '2014-2-19' ), ( '2014-2-20' ), ( '2014-2-21' ) ;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try using CTE. Below query returns 7 days of week considering Sunday as week start day.

```
;WITH t 
     AS (SELECT Dateadd(wk, Datediff(wk, 0, Getdate()), -1) AS WeekD, 
                1                                           cnt 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT weekd + 1, 
                cnt + 1 
         FROM   t 
         WHERE  cnt + 1 < 8) 
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20), weekd, 106) WeekDate, 
       Datename(dw, weekd)               Name 
FROM   t
```

Comment: What if my first day of the week is sunday Can I user DateFirst ?

Comment: Please check the edited answer with sunday as week start day.

Comment: Yes, Thanks and how I could get the records from my custom table ? Should the "In" parameter from your query work ?

Comment: I didn't get you... what types of dates/range does your custom table belongs?

Comment: I have one table, which have various dates.. Nd I want to get that records based on the current week.. Means what is the transaction for current week

Comment: Yes, u can add a `IN` statement. So the query will look like `select * 
From @TableX
where [Date] in (select WeekD From T)`.

Answer (score 1):

This will get all reacords with same week number and same year.

```
select * from cal where date_format(cal_date,'%v') = date_format(now(),'%v') and date_format(cal_date,'%Y')=date_format(now(),'%Y');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this proc

```
Create PROCEDURE getAllDaysBetweenTwoDate
(
@FromDate DATETIME,    
@ToDate DATETIME
)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @TOTALCount INT
    SET @FromDate = dateadd(dd,(datediff(dd,-53684,getdate())/7)*7,-53684)
    SET @ToDate = dateadd(dd,((datediff(dd,-53684,getdate())/7)*7)+6,-53684)
    Select  @TOTALCount= DATEDIFF(DD,@FromDate,@ToDate);

    WITH d AS 
            (
              SELECT top (@TOTALCount) AllDays = DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() 
                OVER (ORDER BY object_id), REPLACE(@FromDate,'-',''))
              FROM sys.all_objects
            )
        SELECT AllDays From d

    RETURN 
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

simplest way i can suggest to get a date's week is this>

```
select datepart(wk, [date to test]) as field
```

hope it helps!